# Is there a pythonic way to write this equal function between 2 vectors dictionaries?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, math, vector

Is there a more efficient/elegant way to write the function 'equal'?

```
def equal(v,u):
  if not v.D==u.D:
    return False 
  if v.f=={} or u.f=={}:
    if not sum(v.f.values())==sum(u.f.values()):
      return False
    else:
      return True
  if not v.f.keys()==u.f.keys():
    if not sum(v.f.values())+sum(u.f.values())==0:
      return False    
  if not sum(v.f.values())==sum(u.f.values()):
     return False
  if not v.D==u.D:
    return False   
  return True
```

Here is the expected output:

```
>>> Vec({'a', 'b', 'c'}, {'a':0}) == Vec({'a', 'b', 'c'}, {'b':0})
True
>>> Vec({'a', 'b', 'c'}, {'a': 0}) == Vec({'a', 'b', 'c'}, {})
True
>>> Vec({'a', 'b', 'c'}, {}) == Vec({'a', 'b', 'c'}, {'a': 0})
True
```

Be sure that `equal(u, v)` checks equalities for all keys from `u.f` and `v.f` even if some keys in `u.f` do not exist in `v.f` (or vice versa)

```
>>> Vec({'x','y','z'},{'y':1,'x':2}) == Vec({'x','y','z'},{'y':1,'z':0})
False
>>> Vec({'a','b','c'}, {'a':0,'c':1}) == Vec({'a','b','c'}, {'a':0,'c':1,'b':4})
False
>>> Vec({'a','b','c'}, {'a':0,'c':1,'b':4}) == Vec({'a','b','c'}, {'a':0,'c':1})
False

# The keys matter:
>>> Vec({'a','b'},{'a':1}) == Vec({'a','b'},{'b':1})
False

# The values matter:
>>> Vec({'a','b'},{'a':1}) == Vec({'a','b'},{'a':2})
False
"""
```

Here is the `Vec` Class:

```
class Vec:
    """
    A vector has two fields:
    D - the domain (a set)
    f - a dictionary mapping (some) domain elements to field elements
        elements of D not appearing in f are implicitly mapped to zero
    """
    def __init__(self, labels, function):

        self.D = labels
        self.f = function
```

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to want to do is to define your vectors as equal if attributes `D` are equal and if `f` are equal excluding entries with value `0`. This is how you can do it.

```
def equal(v, u):

    # We will remove the entries with value zero for comparison
    non_zero_v_f = {key: val for key, val in v.f.items() if val != 0}
    non_zero_u_f = {key: val for key, val in u.f.items() if val != 0}

    return v.D == u.D and non_zero_v_f  == non_zero_u_f
```

Furthermore you can make that a special class method so the `==` will actually use it for equality.

```
class Vec:
    def __init__(self, labels, function):

        self.D = labels
        self.f = function

    def __eq__(v, u):

        non_zero_v_f = {key: val for key, val in v.f.items() if val != 0}
        non_zero_u_f = {key: val for key, val in u.f.items() if val != 0}

        return v.D == u.D and non_zero_v_f  == non_zero_u_f
```